# DXA 1.7 TBBs - ILMerge issue when building from source

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

I've downloaded the [DXA 1.7 C# TBBs](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/tree/release/1.7) and would like to build them and use my build for the DXA TBBs.  However, I'm getting the following error from `ILMerge`. It seems `'Error 3'` is the inability for it to find a directory or file.  What files should I have in the `C:\_references\cm-8.1` folder?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The command ""C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe"  ^
>       /out:Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.merged.dll ^
>       /targetplatform:v4 ^
>       /lib:C:_references\cm-8.1 ^
>       Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.dll DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.dll DD4T.ContentModel.dll DD4T.Serialization.dll DD4T.Templates.Base.dll
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll " exited with code 3. Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is described in the [README.md file](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/1.7/README.md) of the dxa-content-management repository on GitHub:

> Note that the `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.csproj` project references CM assemblies in `_references` subdirectories which are not included in this repository, because these assemblies cannot be distributed without a signed license agreement. In order to build the project, the following CM assemblies will have to be obtained from an SDL Web/Tridion distribution and put in the appropriate `_references` subdirectories:

`cm-8.1`:

- `Tridion.Common.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.Common.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.TemplateTypes.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.TypeRegistration.dll`
- `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll`
- `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll`
- `Tridion.Logging.dll`
- `Tridion.TopologyManager.Client.dll`
- `Microsoft.OData.Client.dll`
- `Microsoft.OData.Core.dll`
- `Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll`
- `Microsoft.Spatial.dll`
- `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

By the way, please also note the following bit of text in the README:

> To facilitate upgrades, it is highly recommended to use an official, compiled version of the DXA Core TBBs (part of the DXA distribution) instead of a custom build. If you really have to modify the DXA Core TBBs, we kindly request you to submit your changes as a Contribution;

Comment: That's a great README!

Comment: @robrtc thanks, it's only been there since Feb 2016 or so...

Comment: Yeah yeah, check check